# The best way to refresh paginated data on the client side?

Tags: javascript, api, rest

I have a REST API that implements server-side pagination returning the following data:

```
{
  items: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 2
    }
  ],
  nextToken: <some-hash-key> // cursor-based
}
```

How should the client application refresh the list if the resource gets updated (client isn't aware of the update, so this is a pull model)? I have some ideas:

1. fetch all resources at a regular interval (like every 10 seconds)
2. maintain a session ID that rotates every N minutes. When a new session is created, fetch all resources

Both approaches are fundamentally the same idea. The first approach is more costly but allows more real-time updates. The second approach is based on session ID which I think is more idiomatic, but no real-time updates. Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 1):

REST APIs are not designed for real time updates; for that you need sockets.

Answer (score 0):

It is not scalable to update every single update to client-side in realtime, so it has to be an updation at regular interval. The duration/interval time could be decided based on facts on the table.

You can use simple integration like `https://socket.io` and a cron like architecture to broadcast updates in regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Version your list, send [If-None-Match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-None-Match) request headers with GET requests each n secs, or probably mins. Respond with 304 if not modified. Respond with new data if modified. Though this won't scale well. Using websockets and sending an update event scales a lot better. As of sessions REST is stateless, so you don't have those.